# When trying to play recorded audio file using aplay, gets an error saying No such file or directory

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm trying to record and play recorded audio file. I use Armbian. I recorded a audio using  `arecord -D plughw:0,0 --duration=10 test2.wav` command. When I'm trying to play that audio file(test2.wav) using  `aplay test2.wav` I got an error saying `test2.wav: No such file or directory.` But when execute `dir` it shows that the audio file(test2.wav) exists. How can I sort this out?

Comment: What have you done to play it ?! Are you doing it from terminal ?! Are you inside directory thas it is saved ?

Comment: Yes I'm using terminal, and of course at that time I was inside the directory, when I execute dir, it shows the audio file which was recorded

Comment: With absolutely no disrespect intended, have you considered posting this question to one of the `armbian` forums? I ask because it sounds like you know what you're doing, but armbian is probably not the mainstream OS here. Consequently, knowledgeable answers might be a bit harder to get.